# Разница типов данных и объявления переменной от перменной-указателя

Tags: c++, указатели

Хотелось бы понять, ибо c парочкой типов из этого списка я столкнулся когда читал про сокеты на MSDN(тут не весь список, конечно):

```
BOOL,BOOLEAN,BSTR,BYTE,CHAR,DOUBLE,DWORD,DWORD_PTR,DWORD32,DWORD64,DWORD,LONG,FLOAT,HANDLE,HCALL,HRESULT,INT,INT8,INT16,INT32,INT64
```

В чем они уступают или отличаются от допустим `int, long int, short int, char итд`, кроме как регистром или в них нет никакого отличия? Тогда в чем смысл?

Допустим есть такой код:

```
int a;
a = 10;
int *b;
b = new int;
*b = 10;
```

Все что приведено в коде валидно, просто я то ли плохо читал, то ли не уловил суть, зачем мы пишем строку для указателя `b = new int;`? Почему мы тоже самое не пишем для обычной переменной?

Заранее прошу прощения за такие, банальные вопросы

Comment: Во-первых вы задали два разных вопроса, а во-вторых на оба уже есть ответы

Comment: по поводу типов - они все просто дефайнятся через стандартные `int` и т. д. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: да действительно через дефайны, забавно, не знал, спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда вы пишите

```
int a;
```

то для переменной `a` выделяется память либо статическая либо автоматическая в зависимости от того, где переменная объявлена.

Абсолютно тоже самое происходит и с этим объявлением

```
int *b;
```

Различие состоит лишь в том, что для переменой `a` допустимыми значениями являются целые числа типа `int`, а для переменной `b` - значения адресов объектов целого типа, то есть значения типа `int *`

Вы можете написать

```
a = 10;
```

И точно также вы можете написать

```
b = &a;
```

То есть все абсолютно идентично.

Что касается этого предложения

```
b = new int;
```

то оно состоит из нескольких операций. Сначала в динамической памяти создается объект типа `int`, а затем его адрес присваивается переменной `b`.

Различие между двумя этими предложениями

```
b = &a; 
b = new int;
```

состоит лишь в том. что в первом случае переменной `b` вы присваиваете адрес уже существующего именованного объекта, а во втором случае `вы` сначала создаете неименованный объект в динамической памяти, а затем его адрес присваиваете переменной `b`.

Что касается объявлений таких, как эти

BOOL,BOOLEAN,BSTR,BYTE,CHAR,DOUBLE,DWORD,DWORD_PTR,DWORD32,DWORD64,DWORD,LONG,FLOAT,HANDLE,HCALL,HRESULT,INT,INT8,INT16,INT32,INT64

то вы должны учесть, что, например, в C нет булевского типа. Поэтому обычно его заменял либо целый тип либо перечисление.

Или, например, тип `char` может вести себя как `signed char` или как `unsigned char`. Чтобы избежать такой неоднозначности вводился алиас `BYTE`, который вел себя, например, эквивалентно типу `unsigned char`

Все эти алиасы вводились для того, чтобы избежать неоднозначности в коде, введя конкретные характеристики типов такие, как разрядность, знаковость и т.д.

Comment: спасибо, теперь все понял :)